# How to file form 1099 NEC free online

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-1099, online-tools

BH

been looking everywhere, never did taxes before, only had one job where this company gave me a 1099 NEC form [no idea what that means], and so far turbotax, h&r block, ezTaxReturn, nothing. Tried the free filing on the IRS website, but no option for the NEC form. Does the IRS just want people to only work for wages? If not, how can one simply file a 1099 NEC online for free with no hassles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to file it. The form is given to you (and to the IRS) to report your self-employment earnings. This is an informational form.

In order to pay taxes on your income and to report your taxable income and taxes to the IRS you need to file [Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040) (and a similar form to your State, if your State levies income taxes). If you've never filed taxes before, you can start with the [IRS publication 17](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-17).

Comment: So how do those other websites work when they say "enter your 1099 NEC info here" etc., ?

Comment: What other sites? There are sites for filing forms 1099, but it is the payer who files it, not the payee. You're receiving it, not filing it.

Comment: turbotax, eztaxreturn, h&r block, I went on all of them and they all have a section "enter the 1099 NEC details here" [paraphrasing], and they add that to the tax return somehow, what exatly does that do ? [keep in mind I have no idea about how taxes work at all in any way]

Comment: @B''HBi'ezra--BoruchHashem well maybe you should start educating yourself, for example by reading the IRS publication I linked to. The information from 1099 flows to your form 1040 (which is the tax return that you file with the IRS and in which you report all your income and taxes due and paid).

Answer (score 0):

On the other side of this equation:
It's now possible to e-File 1099 forms in IRIS
https://www.irs.gov/filing/e-file-information-returns

Owners of rental properties face this, as the rules now require filing 1099-NEC for contractors, gardeners, and other service providers who worked on the property.